# Source of Infinite Loop

Tags: java

Everytime I run this code, the console goes into an infinite loop printing "Please input a number". I do not understand why this is happening. Thanks in advance.

```
    boolean check = true;
    int temp = 0;
    while(check==true){
        try{

            temp= asker.nextInt();
            check = false;
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("Please input a number.");
        }
    }
```

Edit: asker is a Scanner. The purpose of the code is to loop until an integer is inputted by the user.

Comment: my guess is `asker.nextInt()` is throwing an exception

Comment: Probably InputMismatchException occurs? If you add check = false just after "Please input a number." the code stops?

Comment: What is "asked".    If asker is undefined or does not have a NextInt() function, your code will loop infinitely

Comment: Asker is a scanner. Sorry I should have clarified that in the question.

Comment: Debug the code step by step, you will find "check = false" is never be called,as Exception occurs in "asker.nextInt()".

Comment: I finally got it to work. I changed my code a bit to first accept the input as a string and then parse the input. If you are interested to see it, I posted it as one of the answers. Thanks for all of your comments and input. It helped a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `asker.NextInt()` is throwing an [`InputMismatchException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html), indicating that the input received from `asker` (assuming it's a `Scanner`) isn't actually an integer. This exception causes the loop to restart without setting `check` to false.

Print the exception within the catch block to get more information about the failure. But most likely, you're feeding your application something (lots and lots of something, if it's looping like that) that doesn't actually contain integer values.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. Yes the infinite loop does occur whenever I input a non-integer. What do I need to insert so the loop continuously asks for an input until an integer is inputted?

Comment: That's pretty much what you've got now, @rmp2150. What kind of data are you sending it?

Comment: I am sending it random strings just to test whether it will inform the user that a non-integer value was submitted. However whenever I send a string it continues to print "Please input a number" and never allows the user to input again.

Comment: Huh. It *never* stops looping? Are you sure you aren't just sending the same string over and over? Maybe you've got some console weirdness. Try printing the characters you see, using `asker.next()` instead of `asker.nextInt()`, and print the results.

Comment: I further examined my code and I believe the problem is that asker.nextInt() is reading an input the user entered earlier. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You never want to actually "Use" try/catch--by that I mean don't use it as part of your program logic--this is what you are doing.

One big problem is that, like your app, you don't see the stack trace.  Eating a stack trace in an exception is almost always wrong.

If you do have to catch an exception, handle it near the catch as well as you can, but it's better to set up your code so that the exception can't be thrown anyway.

Discard this advice if your teacher told you to do it this way, but remember in the back of your mind that it's poor form.

Also don't tell your teacher that it's poor form :)  he either doesn't know in which case he won't understand why or he does know and is using this to show you how try/catch works.

Comment: Haha Thank you. I am relatively new to programming and I'm not a fan of the try/catch. But I believe my teacher wants to see we are capable of using try/catch.

Answer (score 0):

What is `asker`, a `Scanner`?  If `nextInt()` fails, it doesn't consume any input, so when you catch your exception and loop back around to try again, it ends up just reading the same bad input again.

You should do something in the `catch` block to consume the invalid input, so that the next time around, it can read some *different* input.  Call `asker.nextLine()` maybe, and ignore the return value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to break the loop and report why the loop occurs

```
boolean NotValid = true;
int temp = 0;
while(NotValid){
    try{

        temp= asker.nextInt();
        NotValid = false;
        break; // stop
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException e){
        System.out.println("Please input a number. reason why:");
        System.out.println(e);
        NotValid = true;
    }
}
```